# Sparx EA template fragment scripting not outputs any data

Tags: xml, jscript, enterprise-architect

Followed this instruction [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/reporting/custom_script_fragments.html)

Created my own `document template fragment` wiht custom field inside.
Binded custom script to it (code will be below)

Created `document` template which contain my  `document template fragment`(in template fragment inside `custom` tag I added custom fields like `Author` and `TimeGen`)

Used document generation on it but what I get is an empty document!
Why this is happen?

I got Sparx Ea 12 version

Script code (copied from example [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/report_generation/example_rtf_template_fragment_.html))

```
function MyRtfData(objectID) {
    var i;
    var xmlDOM = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDOM.validateOnParse = false;
    xmlDOM.async = false;
    var node = xmlDOM.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'");
    xmlDOM.appendChild(node);
    var xmlRoot = xmlDOM.createElement("EADATA");
    xmlDOM.appendChild(xmlRoot);
    var xmlDataSet = xmlDOM.createElement("Dataset_0");
    xmlRoot.appendChild(xmlDataSet);
    var xmlData = xmlDOM.createElement("Data");
    xmlDataSet.appendChild(xmlData);
    var xmlRow = xmlDOM.createElement("Row");
    xmlData.appendChild(xmlRow);
    var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("DateGen");
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }
    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    xmlName.text = today;
    xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
    var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("TimeGen");
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    xmlName.text = hours + ":" + minutes + " ";
    xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
    var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("Author");
    xmlName.text = Session.UserName;
    xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
    var xmlName = xmlDOM.createElement("EA_REPOS");
    xmlName.text = Repository.ConnectionString;
    xmlRow.appendChild(xmlName);
    return xmlDOM.xml;
};
```

When I running it in debugging mode it seems like okay, it outputs some xml structure, but when I generate document - I got just emtpy sheet

**UPD:**

Now I get rtf error, and system output just empty

Error looks like that:
[image]

**UPD2:**

When I debug it it output valid XML

Comment: If the system tells you about errors in the system output and that is empty you should report a bug to Sparx.

Comment: @ThomasKilian oh well, suddenly I solved the problem! strange way, but, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved! By that I mean that I can generate documents with custom fields using `template framents + scripts` mechanism.

What I've done (long story short - started everything from scratch):

1. Made new script group
2. Created there new `JScript` file (the one
       above code was contained in `Javascript` file, maybe it was the
       reason)
3. Created new `fragment template`, made custom `Autor` field
       there
4. Created `template`, added there my `fragment template`